# What is the recording location, studio, and year of the song "That's What Friends Are For"?

Tags: recording

YouTube URL:

What is the recording location, studio place, and year of the beautiful song "That's What Friends Are For"?

Comment: I assume you're specifically asking about the Dionne Warwick ("Dionne & Friends") version, not the original by Rod Stewart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was recorded in 1985 at Conway Studios in Hollywood.

According to Dionne Warwick's autobiography:

> One day in 1985, I ran into Elton John at the supermarket in Los Angeles the day before the ["That's What Friends Are For"] recording session.<sup>1</sup>

> The recording session for "That's What Friends are For" was done at Conway Recording Studios in Hollywood.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup>Dionne Warwick, *My Life, as I See It: An Autobiography* (Atria Books, 2010), p. 109–10. ([Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=z_7igwZUWX0C&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=studio%20los%20angeles%20%22that%27s%20what%20friends%20are%20for%22))

<sup>2</sup>Ibid., 110.